# Convert .zip to Bytestring in Jython

Tags: python, file, type-conversion, jython

I need to convert a .zip file to a Bytestring in python; is there a method to make this conversion? Do i need to import a library?
I tried open('filepath', 'rb') and file.read(), bytes()... almost everything, but it seems that is not working, using type() on the variable generally says array.array
I'm not working on Python 3.x

thanks for your replies!

EDIT: here's a code example:

`

```
filePath = "/location/"                     
fileName = "filename.zip"
file = open(filePath+fileName, "rb")
byteconverted = file.read()
file.close()
```

`

(in this case is not returning array.array, i just need to know how to create a bytestring from a .zip file, sorry for my miscomprension)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? ``open(zippath, 'rb')`` should work just fine – it should definitely *not* provide an ``array.array``.

Comment: Are you working with Python 2? Do you want to create a `BytesIO` object or a bytes object? And the bigger question - what is your overall purpose?

Comment: @MattDMo i'm using Jhyton 2.7 (i guess it's like Python 2.7). I need to convert the file to a Bitestring, to call a method from an OPC-UA server. I tried to call the method but the result is "Bad_InvalidArgument"
Here the full error:

result:((2158690304L, u'Bad_InvalidArgument', u'One or more arguments are invalid.'), [(0L, u'Good', u'Good; unspecified.'), (0L, u'Good', u'Good; unspecified.'), (0L, u'Good', u'Good; unspecified.'), (0L, u'Good', u'Good; unspecified.'), (2158690304L, u'Bad_InvalidArgument', u'One or more arguments are invalid.')], [])

Comment: "(i guess it's like Python 2.7)" It's not, especially for the basic types. I've edited the title and retagged the question to avoid confusing people trying to run your MRE with plain Python.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @MisterMiyagi i appreciate it a lot!